# Filter rows in pandas dataframe where data belong from start of current quarter till the end of current month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am trying to fiter my dataframe to find Quarter to Date (QTD) rows. In the data below, my year starts with Febuary so when i say QTD, i mean as below:

```
Quarter Months
1       Feb, Mar, Apr
2       May, Jun, Jul
3       Aug, Sep, Oct
4       Nov, Dec, Jan
```

```
Sample Dataframe:
Quarter Month   Data    Value
1       1       A       100             
1       2       B       134             
1       3       C       145             
2       4       D       156             
2       5       E       167             
2       6       F       178             
3       7       G       123             
3       8       H       112             
3       9       I       187             
4       10      J       132             
4       11      K       109             
4       12      L       121
```

For current case, lets say my current month is Sep, the data that has been filtered shoud contain rows from Aug-Sep only.

I am able to identify the quarter by using the below function but this is taking start of year from Jan.

```
def current_quarter(dt):
    prev_quarter_map = ((4, -1), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0))
    quarter, yd = prev_quarter_map[(dt.month - 1) // 3]
    return (quarter)
```

Is there a way to filter only those rows which start from current quarter and end till current month?

Comment: Your current_quarter() erroneously gives 4 for `current_quarter(datetime.fromisoformat('2020-03-28'))`. Did I get it wrong?

Comment: @BillHuang : No, i just realised, that function is not working as expected. Working on that

Comment: Besides, I don't get what input would you like to take (a date? a dataframe? or none, just do it for every row?), and what is the expected output (one dataframe? or one dataframe for each row?).  May you elaborate that? Otherwise it is not workable....

Comment: In addition, do you have a year column? Or the data is sorted chronologically already? Otherwise, for January, it can be impossible to distinguish between data from December of "this year" and "last year"....

Comment: The input for this function will be a date in the format ```datetime.date(2015, 1, 13)```. Once I have the required output, I can use it to filter the dataframe. At once instance, dataframe will only contain data from Feb to Jan of that Fiscal year. It wont have any previous year of data

Comment: Do you mean `f(dataframe, date) -> dataframe`? Alright, since somebody is able to get your intention, I give up on this question. Sorry for bothering you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is create dictionary by quarters starting by `February`, then use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by months and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) by datetime `now` converted to your quarters from dictionary `dq`:

```
q = [[2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,10],[11,12,1]]
dq = {x: k for k, v in enumerate(q, 1) for x in v}
print (dq)
{2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 3, 9: 3, 10: 3, 11: 4, 12: 4, 1: 4}

now = dq[pd.to_datetime('now').month]
print (now)
3

df1 = df[df['Month'].map(dq) == now]
print (df1)
   Quarter  Month Data  Value
7        3      8    H    112
8        3      9    I    187
9        4     10    J    132
```

If need filter by some another datetime:

```
date = datetime.date(2015, 1, 13)
now = dq[date.month]
print (now)
4

df1 = df[df['Month'].map(dq) == now]
print (df1)
    Quarter  Month Data  Value
0         1      1    A    100
10        4     11    K    109
11        4     12    L    121
```

EDIT: In solution above is not distinguish between years of quarters, so added new solution for it with [`tseries.offsets.QuarterBegin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.QuarterBegin.html):

```
#add year column
print (df)
    Quarter  Month Data  Value  Year
0         1      1    A    100  2020
1         1      2    B    134  2020
2         1      3    C    145  2020
3         2      4    D    156  2020
4         2      5    E    167  2020
5         2      6    F    178  2020
6         3      7    G    123  2020
7         3      8    H    112  2020
8         3      9    I    187  2020
9         4     10    J    132  2020
10        4     11    K    109  2020
11        4     12    L    121  2020

#convert columns to datetimes and convert to datetime for start oq quarter

df['Q'] = (pd.to_datetime(df[['Month','Year']].assign(Day=1)) + 
           pd.offsets.QuarterBegin(0, startingMonth=2))
print (df)
    Quarter  Month Data  Value  Year          Q
0         1      1    A    100  2020 2020-02-01
1         1      2    B    134  2020 2020-02-01
2         1      3    C    145  2020 2020-05-01
3         2      4    D    156  2020 2020-05-01
4         2      5    E    167  2020 2020-05-01
5         2      6    F    178  2020 2020-08-01
6         3      7    G    123  2020 2020-08-01
7         3      8    H    112  2020 2020-08-01
8         3      9    I    187  2020 2020-11-01
9         4     10    J    132  2020 2020-11-01
10        4     11    K    109  2020 2020-11-01
11        4     12    L    121  2020 2021-02-01
```

Also is added `QuarterBegin` to datetime and last fitler by it:

```
date = datetime.date(2020, 1, 13)
custom_q = (date + pd.offsets.QuarterBegin(0, startingMonth=2))
print (custom_q)
2020-02-01 00:00:00


df1 = df[df['Q'] == custom_q]
print (df1)
   Quarter  Month Data  Value  Year          Q
0        1      1    A    100  2020 2020-02-01
1        1      2    B    134  2020 2020-02-01
```